# Web Service war granularity best practices

Tags: soa

Is it better to have lots of small deployments with a few web services per war, or to have one big deployment with lots of web services per war?

In this case, assume that all of the web services share a common backend and will benefit from code-sharing. For small wars shared code would have to be put into a jar project and included from all the smaller deployments. Now each war can be tested/deployed separately, but if the backend changes they all need to be updated rather than only one.

The backend in this case is yet another web service provided by a vendor. Updates to it are usually backwards compatible but not always.

I know there is no clear-cut answer but any experience shared will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule you'd want one war per service. The point is that a service does not have to be a single web-service (in fact some of the endpoint can be other technologies not just web-services). A service can expose multiple endpoints and contracts. 
You'd group together related contracts e.g a service that handles user management can have APIs for both users and groups. However APIs related to Orders probably belong in a different service (and thus war).
If you slice the services pieces that are too small you can get what I call the [nano-service antipattern](http://arnon.me/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/Nanoservices.pdf) where the overhead of a service is more than the utility you get from it

[image]